# Make a hover dropdown parent link only work when the dropdown children are displayed

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have a classical dropdown hover menu, but the hover element is also a link in itself. It works fine in desktop, but on mobile I have the problem that I haven't found a way to display the dropdown, without following the link. For example:

```
  <li><a href="page1.html">Dropdown parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Dropdown element</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Dropdown element</a></li>
        <li><a href="page4.html">Dropdown element</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

So, on desktop you can normally hover over the parent, click it if you want, or click any of the dropdown elements. But on mobile, as there is no hover, you have to click the dropdown parent to be able to see the elements, but that would take you to the dropdown parent link.

Is there a way to make the link work only on the second click? Or only when the dropdown elements are being displayed? Thanks.

Comment: The solution I most often see, is an additional `[+]` icon (or one with a triangle pointing downward) inserted at the right side of the parent link - so that clicking the link still navigates to that page as normal, and if users want to see the submenu items, then they would have to explicitly click on that extra item. Much less confusion for users IMHO, than if the same action (click on the parent link itself) would trigger different kinds of reactions.

Comment: The default behavior on touch-devices is that `hover` event becomes a `tap`. Therefore, the usual way of dealing with this is either through `[+]` as @CBroe mentioned above or making the parent anchor not follow link by adding `href="javascript:void(0)"` and adding the link as a child to the parent with a label like "Overview". Making the parent on touch-device as a double-click is possible via JavaScript but is really bad for user-experience. For example, if a user taps on parent, it will open the dropdown, but the second tap should close the dropdown instead of going to the link.